# How to create win percentage for dataset in r

Tags: if-statement, subset, percentage

I have a dataset for the whole 2021 MLB season in r, but it does not give me the win percentage. I have a column for total games as well as score of the game. I was thinking about using ifelse opponent score<team score and then dividing it by the number of games the team played, but am running into a lot of troubles getting it done. I was also wondering if it was possible to then seperate that by each 162 lines so that I can get it by team as opposed to the whole set.

I have tried using ifelse to create it, but every time I do say it comes with 1 for each game and I don't know how to put it down for 0 if they lose/what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Share the code, it will be easier to fix you specific error when we see it. Generally an if else statement should suffice.